# jQuery UI вызывается сразу несколько диалоговых окон (Dialog)

Tags: jquery-ui

Всем здрасти. :)
Делаю сайт, в админ панели есть редактор новостей. При клике по новости, должно появиться диалоговое окно с формой, для редактирования новости.

```
$(".edit").click(function () {
            var elementId = $(this).parent().attr("rel");
            $.get("/Admin/EditNews", { id: elementId }, function (data) {

                $(data).dialog({ modal: true, title: "Редактор новости", width: 580, height: 450 });

            });

        });
```

То есть, форма запрашивается через get, и затем, помещается в диалоговое окно.
На самом деле, всё корректно работает, кроме одного момента. Почему - то ПЯТЬ диалоговых окон появляется. С формой только одно, остальные 4 только с заголовком. И чтобы начать редактировать новость, сперва надо закрыть первые 4. )

Что это за баг такой?

Comment: А в data у вас разве объект jquery? Рискну предположить, что там 5 дивов и jquery их парсит)

Comment: сейчас посмотрим. )

Comment: хм, data сделал return json. Возвращает да, несколько ДИВов. но не пять, и всё это в одном общем диве. результат абсолютно тот же.

Comment: Да, похоже, дело в data. Если вывести что - либо другое, срабатывает нормально. Осталось найти, в чём причина.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так: (впилите в документ див с id, допустим, myDialog, и в data возвращайте как обычно текст)

```
$.get("/Admin/EditNews", { id: elementId }, function (data) {
  $('#myDialog').html(data);
  $('#myDialog').dialog({
    modal: true,
    title: "Редактор новости",
    width: 580,
    height: 450
    });
  });
```

Comment: То, что надо, благодарю.  
Кстате, а количество дополнительных диалогов приравнивалось количеству <script> ТЭГов, которые так же были в data переменной. :)